# How to create a shifting colour hue in Asprite

Tags: color, pixel-art

I am new to learning pixel art and trying to study from examples, such as in the image below: I would like to understand what tools exist to simplify the shade/gradient transition effect below (rather than manually shifting the shade for each pixel). Looking at a given top to bottom strip such the central vertical brown line a transition effect of each pixel going from dark to light and back to dark again - is there a tool/brush/add on that can automate this?

As it would seem quite hard work to change each pixel for a big image, or am I thinking of this the wrong way?

So far I have researched the use of shading tool in aseprite, which only allows you to shift between three colours, the gradient tool only seems to work with paint bucket, the blur tool sometimes has this effect but is random pot luck.

many thanks

[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time coming up with a good answer for you. I think it's partly because pixel art simply *is* that hard. It's common for pixel artists to insist on using a limited palette and manually placing each pixel. It's hard to imagine a tool which would be able to "predict" exactly which variations you want. The *Gradient Tool* could be used on a selection, but can only be horizontal or vertical. *Shading* might be more useful. It's *not* confined to three colors - you can select a whole range and afterwards drag the colors around.

Comment: @Wolff really appreciate your answer, thanks! I thought that may be the case, I mean the time and effort put into this alone must be huge, each pixel is shifted slightly. In some cases its mirrored in other cases its more natural. Amazing.